# C# TreeView Nodes

Tags: c#

I'm going to make this as clear as I can, if I leave any details out that would help you help me get it working right, please let me know.

Ok, so what I want to do is:

I have a treeview list, which I want to add Parent Nodes and Child Nodes to, based on ID's.

So, ID's could come in like 32736 and I want it added to the Treeview (Even if it doesn't have any value between 6 - 32736)

Is there anyway possible of doing this? thanks.

Comment: Is this a WinForms TreeView, or an Asp.NET TreeView?

Comment: A treeview implies a hierarchy and your question needs to better explain what constitutes a parent node vs. a child node. Perhaps you can provide a few examples of the input data and where on your treeview you'd expect each to appear.

Comment: "I have a treeview list" - there is no such thing. Also tag WinForms, WPF or WebForms

Answer (score 1):

You can add nodes with any key (id) you want if you're adding them manually.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57aa8e09.aspx for WinForms.  It's pretty much the same code for the Asp.Net TreeView.

code for defining a new Asp.Net Treenode here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12bxet86.aspx

Then just add it to the collection

```
TreeNode myNewNode = new TreeNode("SomeTextToDisplay", "SomeId");
myTreeView.Nodes.Add(myNewNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodes.aspx  When adding the nodes make sure to do it from the primary UI thread to avoid a cross thread exception or use the TreeView.BeginInvoke() method to have the action performed on the correct thread.

```
TreeViewToModify.BeginInvoke(delegate() => TreeViewToModify.Nodes.Add(new TreeViewNode(id)));
```

Keep in mind this is not taking into account adding to specific parent/child nodes but the logic is the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();
TreeNode root = new TreeNode("Base");
TreeView1.Nodes.Add(root);
TreeNode sub = new TreeNode("32736");
root.Nodes.Add(sub);
```